# WP Contact Form 7 multiple placeholder styles

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm building a WP site with multiple CF7 forms that require different styles. I'm done except for the placeholder style. The main form placeholder pseudoelements work fine, but I'm struggling to properly identify the pseudoeleemnts for the second form's placeholder.

Here's the code for my main placeholder (works fine):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: #3B47BD;
}
:-moz-placeholder { 
    color: #3B47BD;
}
::-moz-placeholder { 
    color: #3B47BD;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: #3B47BD;
}
```

For the second form, I've tried adding the form #id before the pseudoelements with no luck.

Can anyone shed some light? I'm a rookie, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML of each of the forms? Also, when you added the form ID was that code above or below the code you've shown here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Fencer.

I figured it out. In cleaning up the code to paste it here, it occurred to me to id the styles for EACH of the forms. So I created two sets of placeholder styles, like above, but with the form IDs, ie, 

`code`
#IDform1 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: #3B47BD;
}
#IDform2 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: #3B47BD;
}

I guess all I needed was a little push! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You should post the answer to your own question. It might help someone else. Glad you got it working.